# In app billing module java exception occured

Tags: javascript, android, module, titanium, in-app-billing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In app billing java uncaught exception occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694109/in-app-billing-java-uncaught-exception-occured)

Hi I am using the in app billing module in titanium but it is saying that Uncaught java exception occured.Could you help me in this regard what is the problem.Here is my code

```
 var InAppBilling = require('ti.inappbilling');
 InAppBilling.startBillingService();
 InAppBilling.requestPurchase({
productId : 'jesse',
productType : InAppBilling.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP,
//developerPayload : devPayload
});
```

Thanks in advance

```
   [WARN][ActivityManager(   76)] Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.MarketBillingService.BIND }: not found
  [ERROR][BillingService( 1276)] Market Billing Service could not be bound.
 [WARN][System.err( 1276)] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [WARN][System.err( 1276)]  at ti.inappbilling.BillingService.requestPurchase(BillingService.java:214)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at ti.inappbilling.InappbillingModule.requestPurchase(InappbillingModule.java:198)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:60)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:636)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:829)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:307)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 [WARN][System.err( 1276)]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[WARN][System.err( 1276)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
```

Comment: How about a stack trace / error message or anything other than "java exception"?

Comment: Please don't submit the same question again, edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694109/in-app-billing-java-uncaught-exception-occured) if you want to add other information/improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test this on a real device, as emulators don't have Android Market built in. [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) states:

> **Install your application on an Android-powered device.**
>
> You cannot use the emulator to test In-app Billing; you must install your application on a device to test In-app Billing.

Comment: Hi Pearson i have also tried it once on real device and the error was still the same.Could you think there may be other proble or you are sure of real device

Comment: Did it have Android Market (Google Play) installed?